# How to actually show that something is rotating instead of transforming with the rotated object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, manim

The following code does not show me the circle getting rotated about the origin point , instead shows an error message " I think you may have invoked a method
                    you meant to pass in as a Scene.play argument"
other than this i tried to transform the c with a already rotated c2 but it did not show the rotation part that i was hoping for

```
def construct(self):
    self.setup_axes(animate=True)
    d=0.7
    c=Circle(width=d*(2**0.5),fill_color=RED,fill_opacity=0.3)
    c2=Circle(width=d*(2**0.5),fill_color=RED,fill_opacity=0.3)
    vec=np.array([0*d,2*d,0])
    c.move_to(vec)
    self.play(ShowCreation(c),run_time=3)
    vec[0]-=d*1;
    c2.move_to(vec)        
    self.play(Transform(c,c2),run_time=3)
    self.play(c.rotate(PI/2,about_point=np.array([0,0,0])),run_time=3)
    self.wait(3)
```

Comment: do you mean like if a whole image is rotated or a specific object in the image?

Answer (score 0):

> `self.play(c.rotate,PI/2,about_point=ORIGIN,run_time=5)`